# Adding `supports` array to WordPress custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type-support

I am trying to add the `supports` parameter to my custom post type but it is not working and renders the editing page blank:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'my_campaigns',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Campaigns' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Campaign' )
      ),
      'supports' => array(
         'title' => true,
         'editor' => true,
         'thumbnail' => true ),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ]` – different values, not keys.

If we look into `register_post_type()`, we find these lines:

```
if ( ! empty( $args->supports ) ) {
    add_post_type_support( $post_type, $args->supports );
    unset( $args->supports );
} elseif ( false !== $args->supports ) {
    // Add default features
    add_post_type_support( $post_type, array( 'title', 'editor' ) );
}
```

In `add_post_type_support()`, we see that the the values are converted to array *keys* with the value `true`:

```
function add_post_type_support( $post_type, $feature ) {
    global $_wp_post_type_features;

    $features = (array) $feature;
    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        if ( func_num_args() == 2 )
            $_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature] = true;
        else
            $_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature] = array_slice( func_get_args(), 2 );
    }
}
```

`register_post_type()` is calling `add_post_type_support()` with just two arguments, so the `else` in the latter function cannot be reached.

You can however, call `add_post_type_support()` directly and pass custom support features:

```
add_post_type_support(
    'my_campaigns',
    'subheadline',
    [
        'min_length' => 30,
        'max_length' => 300,
    ]
);
```

But then you have to call the function for each feature separately.

*Side note:* Please do not use `'name' => __( 'Campaigns' )`. Without a text domain, this string is not translatable at all, but it triggers a look-up in WordPress default translation, which is rather huge – and slow. See [How to Internationalize Your Plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) for details.

Comment: +1 for the side note, i have seen so many users just using this without text domain